# When resizing down Safari browser Media Queries for higher resolution CSS rules aren't removed, but works fine when reloaded?

Tags: safari, media-queries

[This is the website that I've created](http://unc.site90.net). btw it's my first one ;).

When resizing down the Safari browser it gives me this.

[image].

How do I fix it?

Comment: What is the expected result at lower resolutions? Is the issue the Icons on top of the text vs. positioning to the side?

Comment: @rlcrews Check in FireFox or Chrome, you will get what I mean.